# Send Coordinate info to ViewController from a location class

Tags: ios, objective-c, location

I am trying to write an app, which can update device's locations.

I set up a GPS_Obtainer Class, which will obtain device's location. and GPS_Obtainer class will forward the location info to a view controller.

I tried to use protocol, but it failed.

What is the best way to do it? and how?

Comment: Notifications, or, observers are the best way to do these.

Comment: What about the protocol?  What i was thinking was, GPS_Obtainer will gain the final accurate location info, and send the info to VC.   Basically, GPS_obtainer will do the most hard work, and VC just receive the final location

Comment: Yes Protocols would work as well, other best approach for this is convert `GPS_Obtainer` as a Singleton class, have a property as a delegate and set the delegate to self in the ViewController which will receive it, and don't forget to set it nil when that ViewController will dealloc.

Comment: Yes, That is what i am thinking.  Cheers mate, i am a beginner.  One more question, i know how to transfer data between VCs, but how can i send data from GPS_Obtainer class to VC class? Thanks mate

Comment: I have added an answer check that, it might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to use all three be it `Notification`, `Observers`, or `Protocol` to send location updates, I am demonstrating Protocol way, see below

First you can create a `Singleton` for your `GPS_Obtainer` class like below.

**`GPS_Obtainer.h`**

```
#import "GPS_Obtainer.h"

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol GPS_ObtainerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)locationDidUpdated:(CLLocation *)location;

@end

@interface GPS_Obtainer : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<GPS_ObtainerDelegate> delegate;

+ (GPS_Obainer*)sharedSingleton;

@end
```

**`GPS_Obtainer.m`**

```
@interface GPS_Obtainer()<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager* locationManager;

@end

@implementation GPS_Obtainer

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
        [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    return self;
}

+ (GPS_Obtainer*)sharedSingleton {

    static GPS_Obtainer *sharedSingleton = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       sharedSingleton = [GPS_Obtainer new];
    });
    return sharedSingleton;
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

      if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(locationDidUpdated:)]){
            [self.delegate locationDidUpdated:newLocation];
      }

}

@end
```

Then you just need to set delegate of the class in ViewController which will receive it like below

**`ViewController.m`**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
     [[GPS_Obtainer sharedSingleton] setDelegate:self];
}

-(void)locationDidUpdated:(CLLocation *)location{
    //HERE you get the location updates
}

-(void)dealloc{
  [[GPS_Obtainer sharedSingleton] setDelegate:nil];
}
```

Hope above helps.

Cheers.

Comment: hi, mate, many thanks for your help, and it works well...in terms of the singleton, this is my first time of seeing this designing pattern, would you mind explain the mechanism behind it ?:)

Comment: Singleton -> Are create only once, so when you call `[GPS_Obtainer sharedSingleton]` the object for the class created if not exist, and on multiple calls it will just use the object, since we need the locationmanager in your case it is `GPS_Obtainer` to run always without need to initialise it everytime, so use of Singleton is best here, similarly you can use Singletons for Database Operations.
Protocols - I hope you know.

Comment: And I don't quite get one idea, as shareSingleton is a class method

Comment: `shareSingleton` is a static method of the class, you usually use a lot of singletons in objective-c, like `[NSFileManager defaultManager];`, `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`, singletons are commonly used design pattern in most of the languages, you need read some doc [like this](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/design-patterns-singletons--cms-23886) for more informations.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and help mate, as you know, I am just a beginner :) ...so, basically, sharedSingleton method return a GPS-obtainer object in VC, and set its delegate to be VC.   Because the delegate is strong, I have to reallocate it before VC is dealloc....is that right?

Comment: Yes, `sharedSingleton` returns object of the class, you need to set the delegate nil because if you VC deallocs you `GPS_Obtainer` will still have the delegate reference and it will throw memory leak, so set nil means there is no receiver exist to receive the location updates.

Comment: hi, mate, this morning, i have been reading articles, in terms of Singleton Pattern, if i should ensure only one instance is created in some situations.  So, do i have to override the NSCopy protocol, retain, autorelease...and i tried to override those methods, but retain, autorelease methods are banned in the ARC...my question is, do i have to override those methods? Cheers mate.

Comment: ARC does it all for you, you don't need to worry about Autorelease etc.

Comment: Cheers, mate, you help me a lot

Comment: You may wish to accept my answer if it worked for you, Thanks.

Comment: Yeah mate, I have :)